# vector of closures: cannot borrow `**h` as mutable, as it is behind a `&` reference

Tags: rust

I need a vector of closures which I declared but I cannot use items of the vector due to compile error.

> cannot borrow `**h` as mutable, as it is behind a `&` reference

is it possible to get the code working without dynamic memory allocation?
and why h being borrowed as mutable?

```rust
fn main() {
    let hh: Vec<&dyn FnMut(&mut i32)> = vec![&|i: &mut i32| {
        *i = 10;
    }];

    let mut i = 0;
    let h = &hh[0];
    h(&mut i); // <-- cannot borrow `**h` as mutable, as it is behind a `&` reference
    println!("{}", i);
}
```

I have made above example works but in this case I need to declare variables for each item which looks overabundant

```rust
fn main() {
    let mut item = |i: &mut i32| {
        *i = 10;
    };
    let mut hh: Vec<&mut dyn FnMut(&mut i32)> = vec![&mut item];

    let mut i = 0;
    let h = &mut hh[0];
    h(&mut i);
    println!("{}", i);
}
```

is there an elegant solution?

Comment: Your code compiles if you use `Fn` instead of `FnMut`. Calling an `FnMut` closure requires a mutable reference to the closure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really need the closures to be `FnMut` (they have persisting state), you can `Box` the closures in the vector.

```rust
fn main() {
    let mut state = 0; // Gets move'd to stateful closure.
    
    let mut hh: Vec<Box<dyn FnMut(&mut i32)>> = vec![
        Box::new(move |i: &mut i32| {
            state += 2; // Closure now owns `state` and it persists.
            *i = state;
        })];

    let mut i = 0;
    let     h = &mut hh[0];
    
    h(&mut i);
    println!("{}", i); // Output: 2
    
    h(&mut i);
    println!("{}", i); // Output: 4
}
```

Otherwise, if the closures are `Fn` (stateless) the code is similar to  what you were trying.

```rust
fn main() {
    let hh: Vec<&dyn Fn(&mut i32)> = vec![&|i: &mut i32| {
        *i = 10;
    }];

    let mut i = 0;
    let     h = hh[0];
    h(&mut i); 
    println!("{}", i);
}
```